# Ubuntu 16.04. Can't install Virtualbox 5.1

Tags: server, 16.04, virtualbox

I'm newbie at linux and stuck at vbox installation (ubuntu 16.04 serverx64). I've downloaded .deb archive from official site (virtualbox-5.1_5.1.8-111374~Ubuntu~xenial_amd64.deb). Several times i've been updating dependencies and got the same error:

```
valera@ubuntu-server:~$ sudo dpkg -i virtualbox-5.
virtualbox-5.0_5.0.10-104061~Ubuntu~wily_amd64.deb   virtualbox-5.1_5.1.8-111374~Ubuntu~xenial_amd64.deb
valera@ubuntu-server:~$ sudo dpkg -i virtualbox-5.1_5.1.8-111374~Ubuntu~xenial_amd64.deb
Selecting previously unselected package virtualbox-5.1.
(Reading database ... 262091 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack virtualbox-5.1_5.1.8-111374~Ubuntu~xenial_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking virtualbox-5.1 (5.1.8-111374~Ubuntu~xenial) ...
Setting up virtualbox-5.1 (5.1.8-111374~Ubuntu~xenial) ...
addgroup: The group `vboxusers' already exists as a system group. Exiting.
vboxdrv.sh: failed: modprobe vboxdrv failed. Please use 'dmesg' to find out why.

There were problems setting up VirtualBox.  To re-start the set-up process, run
  /sbin/vboxconfig
as root.
Processing triggers for systemd (229-4ubuntu10) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.15-0ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (1.5-2) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-6ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu5) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.3~bzr0+16.04.20160415-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.59ubuntu1) ...
```

Tried to fix as was written

```
valera@ubuntu-server:~$ sudo /sbin/vboxconfig
vboxdrv.sh: Building VirtualBox kernel modules.
vboxdrv.sh: Starting VirtualBox services.
vboxdrv.sh: Building VirtualBox kernel modules.
vboxdrv.sh: failed: modprobe vboxdrv failed. Please use 'dmesg' to find out why.
```

(also tried do such a thung as root, but the answer is the same)

```
    root@ubuntu-server:/home/valera# /sbin/vboxconfig
    vboxdrv.sh: Building VirtualBox kernel modules.
    vboxdrv.sh: Starting VirtualBox services.
    vboxdrv.sh: Building VirtualBox kernel modules.
    vboxdrv.sh: failed: modprobe vboxdrv failed. Please use 'dmesg' to find out why. 
There were problems setting up VirtualBox.  To re-start the set-up process, run /sbin/vboxconfig as root.
```

Help me please...

Comment: Disable Secure Boot.

Comment: tried "sudo mokutil --disable-validation" and reboot, but nothing changed

Comment: Disable it in BIOS.